# Can I find the axis of rotation for any single-qubit gate?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, bloch-sphere

Suppose I have an arbitrary qiskit $U_3$ gate: $U_3(\theta,\phi,\lambda)$. Is there a way I can find which axis the gate is rotating around? In other words, given any real numbers $\theta,\phi,\lambda$, can I find the vector $\hat n = (n_x,n_y,n_z)$ that the gate corresponds to, so that I can plot the axis of rotation on the Bloch sphere? I'm thinking about the y-z decomposition, but I'm still unable to find out the elements of $\hat n$. How can I figure that out? Thanks a lot for the help:)

Comment: do you mean a single-qubit gate? If so, it's just the eigenvectors. Or even just a single eigenvector really (the two eigenvectors are orthogonal and thus collinear when represented on the Bloch sphere). For unitaries in larger dimensions, you can't, in general, understand the gate as a rotation around a specific axis in state space.

Comment: @glS Thanks for the comment! That helps:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can derive an expression for the rotation axis by combining (1) the decomposition of your unitary $O$ in the Pauli basis, and (2) by the representation of the general rotation operator $R_{\vec n}(\theta)$ in terms of Paulis.

**Step (1)**

Let $\{\sigma_0, \sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z \}$ describe the identity matrix ($\sigma_0 = \mathbb 1$) and Pauli matrices, which together form a basis of $U(2)$, which is the space of single-qubit gates. With the trace as dot-product you can write any matrix $O \in U(2)$ in the basis of Pauli matrices as
\begin{equation}
O = \frac{1}{2} \left(\text{Tr}(O) \sigma_0 + \text{Tr}(O\sigma_x)\sigma_x + \text{Tr}(O\sigma_y)\sigma_y + \text{Tr}(O\sigma_z)\sigma_z \right)
\end{equation}
This is looks like your typical decomposition of a vector into a basis
$$
O = \sum_{\omega \in \{0, x, y, z\}} b_\omega \sigma_\omega,
$$
where the basis coefficients are $b_\omega = \text{Tr}(O\sigma_\omega)/2$ and the basis "vector" (or here matrices) are $\sigma_\omega$.

**Step (2)**

We know that any single-qubit gate can be written as (see e.g. Nielsen & Chuang)
$$
O = e^{i\alpha} R_{\vec n}(\theta)
$$
where
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
R_{\vec n}(\theta) &= e^{i \theta/2 (n_x \sigma_x + n_y \sigma_y + n_z\sigma_z)} \\
&= \cos\frac{\theta}{2}\sigma_0 - i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}(n_x \sigma_x + n_y \sigma_y + n_z\sigma_z)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

The factor $e^{i\alpha}$ is fixed by the determinant of $O$. Since $R$ is a rotation the determinant is $1$, but $O$ might not have a determinant of $1$. So we know that
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\text{det}(O) = \text{det}(e^{i\alpha} R_{\vec n}) = e^{2i\alpha}\det(R_{\vec n}(\theta)) \\
&\Leftrightarrow e^{i\alpha} = \sqrt{\det(O)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

**Combining (1) and (2)**

Now that we know $e^{i\alpha}$  we can match the entries of the Bloch vector $\vec n = (n_x, n_y, n_z)$ with the basis coefficients above! I'll leave the math now out because this post is long enough but if you match
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}(O) &= e^{i\alpha}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\text{ and } \\
\frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}(O\sigma_\omega) &= -i\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \text{ for } \omega = x, y, z
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

You finally obtain
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\theta = 2\cos^{-1}\left(e^{-i\alpha}\frac{\text{Tr}(O)}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
n_\omega = \frac{e^{-i\alpha}\text{Tr}(O\sigma_\omega)}{-2i \sin(\theta/2)} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
which you could possibly simplify further by plugging in the expression for $\theta$, but, as many textbooks say, I'll leave that exercise for the motivated reader. :)

If you do this for e.g.
$$
S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & i \end{pmatrix}
$$
you obtain
$$
\alpha = \frac{\pi}{4}, \theta = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
and
$$
\vec n = (0, 0, 1).
$$

Comment: Thanks so much for the really detailed answer! Could you explain a little bit about what does $\Tr {O(\sigma_\omega)\sigma_\omega}$ mean? For a general $U_3\in SU(2)$, could the expression of $O$ be further simplified?

Comment: there is a little sign mistake. The correct formula would be $\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
R_{\vec n}(\theta) &= e^{i \theta/2 (n_x \sigma_x + n_y \sigma_y + n_z\sigma_z)} \\
&= \cos\frac{\theta}{2}\sigma_0 + i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}(n_x \sigma_x + n_y \sigma_y + n_z\sigma_z)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}$. Check the derivation (2) on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices

Answer (score 9):

1. A generic $2\times2$ (special) unitary matrix decomposes in terms of Pauli matrices as
   $$U = a_0 I + i \sum_{j=1}^3 a_j \sigma_j,\tag U$$
   for $a_j\in\mathbb R$ such that $\sum_{j=0}^3 a_j^2=1$.
   One way to write this condition is to parametrise the coefficients as
   $$a_0 = \cos(\theta),
   \qquad a_j = \sin(\theta) n_j$$
   for any $\theta\in\mathbb R$ and $(n_1,n_2,n_3)\in\mathbb R^3$ such that $\|\vec n\|=1$.
   To be more explicit, this corresponds to the matrix
   $$U = 
   \begin{pmatrix}
   a_0 + ia_3 & i(a_1-ia_2) \\
   i(a_1+ia_2) & a_0 - ia_3\\
   \end{pmatrix}
   = \begin{pmatrix}
   c+i sn_3 &
   is(n_1-in_2) \\
   is(n_1+in_2) &
   c-is n_3
   \end{pmatrix},$$
   where $c\equiv \cos(\theta), s\equiv \sin(\theta)$.
   The eigenvectors of such a matrix are
   $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\|\vec a\|(\|\vec a\|\mp a_3)}}\begin{pmatrix}a_3 \mp \|\vec a\| \\ a_1 + i a_2\end{pmatrix},\tag1$$
   where $\|\vec a\|^2\equiv \sum_{j=1}^3 a_j^2$.
2. Given an arbitrary complex vector $(\alpha,\beta)\in\mathbb C^2$, you can get the corresponding vector in the Bloch sphere via the mapping (more precisely, [this is a bijection $\mathbb{CP}^1\to S^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration)):
   $$\begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\end{pmatrix}
   \longleftrightarrow
   \begin{pmatrix}2\operatorname{Re}(\bar\alpha\beta) \\ 2\operatorname{Im}(\bar\alpha\beta) \\ |\alpha|^2-|\beta|^2\end{pmatrix}.\tag2$$

Putting these facts together you can get the Bloch representation of the eigenvectors of a generic $2\times2$ special unitary matrix.
More explicitly, using (1) and (2) together, we see that the Bloch representations of the two eigenvectors of the $U$ defined in $(\mathrm U)$ are precisely the (normalised versions of the) vectors $\pm(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, as one might have expected from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that helps a lot:) I'm just wondering does that matter if the sign in the expression of $U$ is changed to $-$? Parametrizing $a_0$ as $\cos(\theta/2)$ have the same effect, right?

Comment: what sign? Here $a_j$ are arbitrary real parameters, so $a_j\to -a_j$ gives another valid unitary, if that's what you are asking

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking. Thanks!!

Comment: also related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/23351/55

Answer (score 3):

Thanks all for reading and answering the question, just a correction for the mapping:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\end{pmatrix}
\longleftrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}2\operatorname{Re}(\bar\alpha\beta) \\ 2\operatorname{Im}(\bar\alpha\beta)\\|\alpha|^2-|\beta|^2\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This could be derived from the spherical-coordinate representation of $\hat n$ (note that $n_z=\cos\theta$) and the single-qubit representation:)

Comment: if you are referring to my answer, do you mean that I should have put the $n_z$ component in the third element of the vector? Well that depends on the conventions adopted in defining the Bloch sphere, but I suppose this way is more standard. I'll fix the post (btw, this should really be a comment, not an answer per se)

Comment: @glS Got it. Thanks:)