# What is the general formula for unitary rotations in terms of Pauli spin operators?

Tags: unitarity

Recently I have read a paper in which they have used a unitary transformation as follows:

$$U_{\frac{7\pi}{16}}=\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{8}\right)\sigma_{z}+\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{8}\right)\sigma_{x}$$

Here $ \sigma_{x} $ and $\sigma_{z}$ are the Pauli operators. I didn't understand where this came from? Also are any other combinations of sigma operators with any angles is a Unitary rotation? Do anyone know of any general formula for Unitary rotation? Any references would be great.
Please see Eq. (3) in the paper: [Experimental test of local observer-independence](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.05080).

Why I am concerned about the above unitary operator is:
[image: d]
Please see the below definition for the rotation operators. Here there is an imaginary $i$ coming which is not in the paper I have mentioned.

Comment: It may be helpful if you link the paper (and mention the section where that transformation is introduced) you're talking about

Comment: @epelaaez  Edited the question with the link

Comment: $e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}n\cdot\sigma}$ is rotation around $\vec{n}$ about $\theta$ angle. You can find this in [Nielsen's book](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf), chapter 4.

Comment: @narip But then there would be a factor of i, I cant find that in the paper

Comment: You only need to see that $UU^\dagger=I$, hence it's unitary. As for the reason why there is no imaginary part because it's a specific angle(e.g., when $\theta$ in your rotation is 2$\pi$, there will also miss the imaginary part).

Comment: @narip How many combinations of Pauli matrices will be there then such that the rotations are unitary

Comment: see also https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16552/55: the $2\times2$ (special) unitary matrices are all and only the matrices of the form $a_0 I + i\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i \sigma_i$ with $(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3)\in S^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting $\theta=\pi/2$ for a general rotation, you get
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\pi/2 A} = \mathrm{i} A\,,
$$
which is unitary and up to a global phase $\mathrm{i}$ the operator $A$ itself. Now define a new
operator $U=-\mathrm{i}A$ and it follows
that $U$ is unitary
$$
U^\dagger U = \mathrm{i}(-\mathrm{i}) A^\dagger A = I\,.
$$

You can decompose $A$ into
$$
A = n_x \sigma_x + n_y \sigma_y + n_z \sigma_z
$$
with
$$
n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2 = 1
$$ and $n_i \in[-1,1]$, $i=x,y,z$. In your example
$$
n_x = \sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{8}\right) \qquad
n_y = 0 \qquad
n_z = \cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{8}\right)\,.
$$
For more details see [Nielsen and Chuang, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Computation_and_Quantum_Information).