# Finding the rotation axis and angle in a Bloch sphere for a arbitrary quantum gate

Tags: quantum-gate, bloch-sphere

I have an arbitrary single qubit quantum gate $U_3(t,f,l)$ that transforms (rotates) a given qubit $q$ into the target qubit $p$.
$$\begin{align}U_3(t,f,l) q = p && t,l,f \in \mathbb{R}; q,p \in \mathbb{C^2} \end{align}$$
with
$$U_3(t,f,l) = \begin{pmatrix}\cos{\frac{t}{2}} & - e^{i l}\sin{\frac{t}{2}} \\ e^{i f} \sin{\frac{t}{2}} & e^{i(f+l)} \cos{\frac{t}{2}} \end{pmatrix}$$
I'm able to transfer the qubits $q$ and $p$ into their Bloch sphere representations $q'$ and $p'$. But what is the Bloch sphere representation of $U_3$? There must be a matrix $R_{(\vec{v},r)}$ that fulfills this equation:
$$\begin{align}R_{(\vec{v},r)} q' = p' && R_{(\vec{v},r)} \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}; q', p' \in \mathbb{R}^3\end{align}$$
with
$$\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{pmatrix};u,v,w,r \in \mathbb{R};u^2+v^2+w^2=1$$
where $\vec{v}$ is the rotation axis within the Bloch sphere and $r$ is the turning angle. For example, for the Hadamard gate this would be $\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $r=\pi$.

I'm aware about https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16538/21105 but there seems to be an important step missing at the end.

Comment: what step are you saying is missing in the answers to the linked post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Decompose the matrix into the Pauli basis $U = wI + x(iX) + y(iY) + z(iZ)$.
2. The coefficients you got can be multiplied by a common phase factor so that they are all on the real line. After phasing them like that, the coefficients are the same coefficients as a [quaternion rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) $w + \hat{i}x + \hat{j}y + \hat{k}z$.
3. Convert the quaternion rotation [to an axis angle rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Recovering_the_axis-angle_representation). The ijk part tells you the axis and the length of the real part is related to the angle.

Here's the code in Quirk ([in the Matrix class](https://github.com/Strilanc/Quirk/blob/master/src/math/Matrix.js#L1192)) that does it:

```
    /**
     * Given a single-qubit operation matrix U, finds φ, θ, and v=[x,y,z] that satisfy
     * U = exp(i φ) (I cos(θ/2) - v σ i sin(θ/2))
     *
     * @returns {!{axis: !Array.<!number>, angle: !number, phase: !number}}
     */
    qubitOperationToAngleAxisRotation() {
        Util.need(this.width() === 2 && this.height() === 2, "Need a 2x2 matrix.");
        Util.need(this.isUnitary(0.01), "Need a unitary matrix.");

        // Extract orthogonal components, adjusting for factors of i.
        let [a, b, c, d] = this._2x2Breakdown();
        let wφ = a.plus(d);
        let xφ = b.plus(c).dividedBy(Complex.I);
        let yφ = b.minus(c);
        let zφ = a.minus(d).dividedBy(Complex.I);

        // Cancel global phase factor, pushing all values onto the real line.
        let φ = seq([wφ, xφ, yφ, zφ]).maxBy(e => e.abs()).unit().times(2);
        let w = Math.min(1, Math.max(-1, wφ.dividedBy(φ).real));
        let x = xφ.dividedBy(φ).real;
        let y = yφ.dividedBy(φ).real;
        let z = zφ.dividedBy(φ).real;
        let θ = -2*Math.acos(w);

        // Normalize axis.
        let n = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
        if (n < 0.0000001) {
            // There's an axis singularity near θ=0. Just default to no rotation around the X axis.
            return {axis: [1, 0, 0], angle: 0, phase: φ.phase()};
        }
        x /= n;
        y /= n;
        z /= n;

        // Prefer θ in [-π, π].
        if (θ <= -Math.PI) {
            θ += 2*Math.PI;
            φ = φ.times(-1);
        }

        // Prefer axes that point positive-ward.
        if (x + y + z < 0) {
            x = -x;
            y = -y;
            z = -z;
            θ = -θ;
        }

        return {axis: [x, y, z], angle: θ, phase: φ.phase()};
    }
```